# Establishing infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, square-numbers

> Establish that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$.

I was studying primitive roots, and it was recently proven that the odd prime divisors $n^2 +1$ are all of the form of $4k+1$.

A proof in Burton's *Elementary Number Theory* assumes that there are finitely many primes of the form $4k+1$. The book lets $N = (2p_1...p_n)^2 +1$  ($p_i$ are the primes of form $4k+1$ then proceeds that this number would have a prime of the form $4k+1$ that is not $p_i$ ($i$ between $1$ and $n$) because $p_i$ does not divide 1, thus does not divide $N$.

I was wondering why you would use $N =(2p_1...p_n)^2+1$, doesn't letting $N=(p_1...p_n)^2 +1$ achieve the exact same thing?

Comment: It isn't true that every prime factor of $n^2+1$ is of the form $4k+1$.  If $n$ is odd then $2$ is a factor.  We want to avoid that case.

Comment: Because $N$ is not generally of a form $4k+1$

Comment: For the purpose of the proof , we could also use the second expression, but we would have to argue more complicated because of the additional factor $2$.

Comment: N does not need to be in the form $4k+1$, just$n^2+1$.  I do not get why having a factor of 2 is relevant, since the number N would still have odd divisors, which would be in the form 4k+1? and every prime 4k+1 would still not be able to divide N?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the body, all the odd prime divsors are 4k+1

Comment: As @Peter remarks, you can do it without the factor of $2$ if you want to, but then you need a separate argument to the effect that $n^2+1$ can't be a power of $2$ (unless $n=0$).  That's an easy exercise and worth doing.  Including the factor of $2$ lets you skip that step.

Comment: Yes, what I said, it would make it slightly more complicated. And yes, it is also worth doing it because it is useful to learn such arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every integer $n$, every *odd* prime divisor $p$ of $n^2+1$ is of the form $p=4k+1$ for some integer $k$. It follows that for every *even* integer $n$, every prime divisor $p$ of $n^2+1$ is of the form $p=4k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ be a finite list of primes. Then every *odd* prime divisor of
$$N=(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots p_m)^2+1,$$
is a prime number of the form $4k+1$, and is coprime to $p_1,\ldots,p_m$. This shows that *if* $N$ has an odd prime divisor, *then* the finite list $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ is incomplete. So it remains to show that $N$ has an odd prime divisor, i.e. that $N$ is not a power of $2$.

On the other hand, *every* prime divisor of
$$M=(2p_1\cdot p_2\cdots p_m)^2+1,$$
is a prime number of the form $4k+1$, and is coprime to $p_1,\ldots,p_m$. This shows that the finite list $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ is incomplete. No further argument is needed.